# Since when are Geordi's parents both Starfleet officers?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In [another](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/185327/since-when-is-riker-the-best-pilot-there-is) episode of Potential Sudden Backstory™, in the season 7 (!) episode "Interface", Geordi's mother, Capt. [Silva La Forge](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Silva_La_Forge) is

> MIA, and his father Cmdr. [Edward M. La Forge](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Edward_M._La_Forge) is planning her funeral.

Is this truly the first canon reference to Geordi's parents being Starfleet officers?

Comment: Edward LaForge is a full commander

Comment: I very much dislike Season 7, partly for its obsession with family members (almost every character has some kind of "family" story in this season).

Comment: @Praxis, precisely why this line of questioning.  Backstory should have been explored before seasons 6 and 7.   Although I'm not sure the point is accurate.  We had Lwaxanna, young Ian Troi, Kern, Alexander, the Rozhenkos, Jack Crusher, Robert Picard, Kyle Riker, Lore, Soong, and Lal.   In season 7, the La Forges, Juliana Tainer, and Ian Troi  Did I miss anyone?

Comment: @ThePopMachine : I just asked a "Since when..." question!

Comment: @ThePopMachine : Aren't you forgetting Crusher's grandmother in the terrible "Sub Rosa", as well as Picard's purported son "Jason Vigo", as well as Worf's human brother...?

Comment: @Praxis, I guess you're right.  That's what I get for going from memory.  So that makes six episodes in season 7 with new family members introduced, right?

Comment: @Praxis, re " Since when... ", I have a prediction.  Ask me in a few days.

Comment: @Praxis: "Attached" is obsessed with backstory too.   I'm tempted to ask a question, but this is the kind of thing where *some people* will jump all over the premise of the question right from the start.

Comment: @ThePopMachine : There are also a couple of episodes in Season 7 that introduce sudden, new elements of Data's relationship to Dr. Noonian Soong.  I count these as part of the "family" obsession.  In any case, you're unfortunately probably right that a certain someone will jump all over your question.  That seems to be the pattern.

Comment: @Praxis:  thank you for noticing.

Comment: So...what was your prediction?

Comment: @Praxis, welp, I was wrong.  Because it was you and not me.

Answer (score 24):

## No, this was established in season 5

From the episode [Imaginary Friend](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Imaginary_Friend_(episode)):

> SUTTER: Commander, I understand that you had a parent who was in Starfleet. 
> LAFORGE: Two of them, as a matter of fact. My father was an exozoologist, my mother a Command officer.

---

Several users have commented on the fact that Geordi describes his parents' occupations in past-tense despite them still performing the roles he describes when we see them in season 7. I believe this can be explained by the context of Sutter's question, and the dialog that follows the excerpt above:

> SUTTER: They must have been posted to a lot of different assignments. 
> LAFORGE: That's putting it mildly. They were always on the move. Some of the time together, sometimes separately. I never knew whether or not I was going to be stationed with my father while he studied invertebrates in the Modean system or on some outpost near the Neutral Zone with my mom. 
> SUTTER: Was that hard on you? 
> LAFORGE: I don't remember it that way. 
> SUTTER: It must have been disruptive if you didn't stay in one place long enough to make friends. 
> LAFORGE: Well, I suppose there were aspects of my childhood that were less than ideal, but to me it was just one long adventure. Children are a lot stronger than you think. As long as they know you love them, they can handle just about anything life throws at them, you know. 
> SUTTER: Thanks, Commander.

Sutter is raising his daughter on board the *Enterprise* and is concerned that moving from starship to starship is negatively affecting her. We see near the end of the second excerpt that Geordi understands the source of Sutter's concern. I infer from this that he replied in past tense because he was thinking about his own childhood experience and how it relates to the source of Sutter's worries.

Comment: ***Was*** appears to have been retconned away for "Interface".   Unless we're to believe he simply meant they **were** while he was growing up, and they **still are**.   Thank you Lt. Cmdr Mitch Hedberg.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Perhaps he had left Starfleet and rejoined before we see him again in season 7.

Comment: **Was** could also refer to their roles when Geordi was a child.

Comment: @Xantec, could.   Still seems life a strange way to phrase that.

Comment: @ThePopMachine People don't often speak perfect grammar all the time. Note that Sutter already said, "was." It's not uncommon to echo someone else's phrasing, even if it isn't exactly what you meant to say or imply. I think you're reading *way* too much into it.

Comment: @jpmc26, I'm not questioning we can reasonably argue that phrasing given the retcon.  I just still think it was in fact retconned-- that the intent of the writer who wrote the original line wasn't in fact that they were still in service at the time.  That's all.  Ultimately, of course it doesn't matter.